# mongoDB update with upsert not working

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use update with upsert while providing a query (userId, folderId, word) but the following is not working.

```
Words.update({
            userId: req.session.passport.user,
            folderId: req.body.folderId,
            word:req.body.addword
        }, {
            $set:{
                userId: req.session.passport.user,
                folderId: req.body.folderId,
                word:req.body.addword,
                meaning: req.body.addmeaning,
                example: req.body.addexample,
                image: req.body.addimage,
                NoCorrectAns: 0,
                createdAt: Date()
            }

        },{
            upsert: true
        });
```

Comment: In your db schema, what are the field types for `userId` and `folderId`?

Comment: What is the error message that you receive?

Comment: userId and folderId are String. And I don't get any error

Comment: userId and folderId are both auto-generated by MongoDB

Comment: My intention here is before I want to insert a new word collection, i want to find whether there's 1 already exist. If true, it rather update than inserting a new one has an identical "Word" property

Comment: Oh, turns out I'm using mongoose. :((. Sr you guys